# Horizontaly aligning placeholder in input field

Tags: html, css, forms

What would be correct approach to aligning placeholder to the top of the field, while input text appearing normally in the middle?

Any way to do that with CSS on input/::placeholder only, or should i rather construct a wrapper with span that would disappear when `active` and input field below it?

Here's a fiddle of what i've got now: https://jsfiddle.net/ejsLfvdn/1/

And that's what it should look like up to customers will:
[image]

The input masks are not the case here, i'm only struggling with the placeholder being aligned to the top, while input should appear normally in the middle. The placeholder MUST disappear after filling input.

Comment: To clarify - you want the placeholder text to remain when text is entered into the field?

Comment: @Paddy Nope, placeholder must disappear, but it should be positioned on the top of the field, unlike input text that should appear normally aligned.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? Surely that would not be placeholder text at that point?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mdchad/pen/qqmJex I think you're looking for this..

Comment: @user123 close but nope, updated Q

Comment: @JamesCoyle updated with image

Comment: Im not sure if we can achieve the disappear feature without using js/jquery

Comment: Are you thinking of some text like label on top of text box which disappears on text input?

Comment: @SanjeevS yeah, i think based on the answers it's not possible to make `placeholder` look like this, so will try making `span`/`label` with css/js instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you will be able to do this by directly targeting the placeholder pseudo class (::placeholder).

Only a small subset of CSS properties can be applied to this element and position is not one of them:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

I think you will need to take the approach of a wrapper with span and input and position appropriately.

Comment: That's what i thought tbh, just wanted to make sure there are no workarounds... :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this with the only issue being the input must have the required attribute.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 220px;
}

.input input:valid + label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.input input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input required id="username" name="username" type="text" />
  <label for="username">Username</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I achieved what you need.

btw, I used `jquery` to hide the placeholder while typing and display it again if the field is empty.

```js
$('.form-control').keyup(function(){
 var val = $(this).val();

  if(val == ""){
    $('.placeholder').show();
  }else{
    $('.placeholder').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.input-cont{
  position: relative;
}
.form-control{
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 8px;
  color: #3dc185;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="input-cont">
        <span class="placeholder">Imię</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translateY(-100%)` on your placeholder to move the text upwards and then give your textbox some padding at the top to reveal the text:

```css
.placeholder-offset {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.placeholder-offset::placeholder {
  color: red;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="placeholder-offset" />
```